# Moving resources from AWS root account to another account in AWS Organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

So, a company I just recently joined has its AWS account in a mess and costs are sky rocketing.
I am using trusted advisor to take action on the recommended items.

My question is that they have resources running in the root account and I want to move them to a separate account in aws organization. What is the most viable option for me?

Thanks
Irfan

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what kind of resource do you have? What I am asking is that are they related to Compute (EC2), Infrastructure (ELB, ECS), Storage, or Database?

Comment: take a look at this 

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/migrate-resources-between-aws-accounts/

Comment: The resources being used are EC2, Aurora MySQL, Load balancers, ASGs, Lambda functions,

Comment: As others suggested, it is helpful to specify the type of resources...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

create new "non-default" VPC under that target (**admin**) account, then you can migrate EC2s and other resources into this new VPC, then setup AWS organization, policies etc.
Default VPC is really just for personal use - cannot be "shared" within AWS organization.